# NSOutlineViewDelegate rowViewForItem being called with nil Item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have a custom subclass of NSOutlineView in which I implement my own delegate method

```
- (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item
```

I've confirmed that the data source is set up correctly, and my implementation of the data source method

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
```

always returns the correct value.

When my program runs, the initialization runs smoothly, with the initial data structure being setup properly. However, as soon as the program gets into its first drawing cycle, it crashed on the heading line of `- (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item {` with message `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Looking at the data, I can see that item is nil.

Why would this be the case? If I'm setting up the data correctly, I don't see why a nil row item should be called.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you store your items array?

Comment: In an NSArray, which still appears to be valid when this crashes.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your ouline view is its own delegate? Item nil is usually the root item. If you don't want a row for the root item you should return nil.

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there ever a case when the root item would have a row associated with it?

Comment: I don't know. Are you sure you always and everywhere return a valid item? Which methods of NSOutlineView did you override?

Comment: Yes, at least the three relevant datasource methods.I finally gave up and recreated everything from scratch. It works, but I never found the source of the problem. Hope it doesn't pop up again. Thanks though!